# PHP GD: draw filled path?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, path, gd

Does anyone know a way to draw a filled path in PHP GD?

I can draw the outline no problem, with iterative calls to `imageline` joining up the path points:

[image]

Filling it, though, so it looks like the below, I'm not sure GD provides any obvious means of filling non-trivial shapes:

[image]

Comment: what about http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php?

Comment: Awesome - this is an answer rather than a comment. If you post it up as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [imagefilledpolygon](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledpolygon.php)

```
imagefilledpolygon — Draw a filled polygon
Description 

bool imagefilledpolygon ( resource $image , array $points , int $num_points , int $color )

imagefilledpolygon() creates a filled polygon in the given image.
```